# Get response header from MicroProfile/Quarkus REST client

Tags: quarkus, microprofile

I'm calling an endpoint where the information I need is returned in the response header (https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/rest-api-create-user-no-user-identifier-in-response/1964/4). How do I retrieve this information if I use Quarkus REST client (https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-client)?

I understand that I can use `@ClientHeaderParam` or `@HeaderParam` for putting header in the response. What I want is the opposite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You RestClient method should return a JAX-RS `Response` object instead of the payload so you can access the header from it via `getHeaders`.

Comment: This is correct, but note that in the reactive case (when return type is `Uni<Response>`) there seems to be a bug: `response.getEntity()` will return null (instead of an `InputStream`) even when the response has a normal body. See also [this issue on Quarkus](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/25496)